# Replace SVG AnimateMotion with another one dynamically

Tags: reactjs, svg, smil

I'm developing a React app that shows the metro trafic on a passed given time period. It shows little trains moving on a Metro map, each train having its own `animateMotion` since they have different speeds and departure time.

What I need to do, is to stop all the `animateMotion` ongoing when the user asks for a different time-period, to replace them with the new ones.

Problem : if I delete them, I encounter DOM problems: 
`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'`.

If I trust React on replacing the data and updating the component, the previous animations are either not stopped (they still pollute the graph), or not started again.

Here is a codePen illustrating the former case (thanks to Radu Luncasu) : https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-trains

Is it possible to do this, using SMIL, React, or CSS 3 ? Or do I need to give a look at 3rd party libraries ?

Comment: take a look at this codepen, I tried to do the basics of what you described and react seems to be doing alright. Perhaps you'll find something in there that helps you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cbaxbq

Comment: also call .beginElement() on your animated object when setting the new state. See my updated answer and codepen.

Answer (score 2):

Update: it looks like the issue is caused by the animation not restarting on react rendering. I've modified the codepen so now it calls

`document.getElementById("ani-circle").beginElement();`

before setting the new state. It's a hacky way to do it, I admit, but can't think of anything else. I guess you could use refs instead of getElementById to make it less hacky.

take a look at this codepen, I tried to do the basics of what you described and react seems to be doing alright. Perhaps you'll find something in there that helps you or perhaps you can replicate the issue so somebody can help.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cbaxbq

Comment: I took your CodePen, and forked it a little bit with my problem : the animateMotions are not with infinite repeteCount.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wf8yxk
With that in count, I can't change the values after it had been finished.

Comment: can't open the fork, I could a couple of hours ago but not anymore

Comment: Thanks, there is an improvement. But I still have a problem with multiple trains, as you can see here https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-trains

Comment: Aha, you can call beginElementAt(delay) like this: ```restartAllTrainsWithDelay = (delay) => {
      const elems = document.getElementsByTagName("animateMotion");
          for(let i=0; i<this.state.number; i++) {
          elems[i].beginElementAt(i*delay)}
  }``` and then `this.restartAllTrainsWithDelay(1)` . That's because beginElement doesn't care for the begin={delay} prop on the animateMotion

Comment: great - one problem for my use case: I don't want the animation to start unless I activate it, how can I achieve this?